# Creating boundaries in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function within R that will ask the user to enter a number and then state whether it is a Armstrong number or not, and after that then proceed to ask the user to input lower and upper boundaries and then R would display the Armstrong numbers within that interval.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Armstrong <- function() {
  num <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
  sum <- 0
  temp <- num
  while(temp > 0) {
    digit <- temp %% 10
    sum <- sum + (digit ^ 3)
    temp <- floor(temp / 10)
  }
```

I am not sure how to fix the function so that it takes the lower and upper boundaries entered and then displays the string of Armstrong numbers in that interval.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a recursive call in your function. `sapply(Lnum:Unum, Armstrong)` calls `Armstrong(i)` for every `i` in `Lnum:Unum`. However, your `Armstrong` function does not take an argument, therefore you get an error. I do not know how to calculate Armstrong numbers, but your function will have to start like this: `Armstrong <- function(i = <DEFAULT_VALUE>){...` and then you have to use `i` (or whatever you call it) inside the function

Comment: Why are you fixing the exponent at `3`? That only works for 3-digit Armstrong numbers. Also -- your approach of a single function both prompting the user for input and verifying a condition isn't good design. Your function should simply check if a number is Armstrong. Then write other functions which *use* this function to e.g. prompt the user for input or check all numbers in a given range.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree with what you are saying, but I am required to do it all in one function. An Armstrong number is equal to the sum of the **cube** of its digits.

Comment: The definition of [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) that I am able to locate online is that a number is Armstrong if it is equal to the sum of the digits raised to the power which is equal to the number of digits. Perhaps your instructor is using a non-standard definition.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that uses the more general definition of an [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) being a number which is equal to the sum of its digit, each of which is raised to the power of the number of digits:

```
Armstrong <- function(n){
  digits <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(n),'')))
  k <- length(digits)
  n == sum(digits^k)
}
```

To find all such numbers in a given range:

```
Armstrong.inrange <- function(a,b){
  nums <- a:b
  nums[which(sapply(nums,Armstrong))]
}
```

For example:

```
> Armstrong.inrange(0,10000)
 [1]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  153  370  371  407 1634
[16] 8208 9474
```

Which agrees with the partial list in the Wikipedia article linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following does what you want.
The function now takes two arguments. Then it loops using `sapply` calling an internal function `arms` that does all the work.
Note that the keyboard input uses function `wait` of package `lava`. You will need to install it first with `install.packages("lava")`.

```
Armstrong <- function(Lnum, Unum) {
    if(!require(lava)) stop("Package 'lava' is not installed.")

    arms <- function(num){
        sum <- 0
        temp <- num
        while (temp > 0) {
            digit <- temp%%10
            sum <- sum + (digit^3)
            temp <- floor(temp/10)
        }
        if(num == sum) {
            paste(num, "is an Armstrong number")
        } else {
            paste(num, "is not an Armstrong number")
        }
    }

    Lnum <- wait()
    Unum <- wait()
    unlist(sapply(Lnum:Unum, arms))
}


Armstrong()
```

Comment: I need to be able to type 'Armstrong()' which will then generate 'Enter a number:' and then will state 'is an armstrong' or 'is not an armstrong'. Then another prompt must ask for 'upper boundary' and 'lower boundary' and then produce a string of armstrong numbers in that boundary inputed by the user - all within one function

Comment: @VPedlar See if this is it.